# How to simplify the code to make it look pretty

Tags: simplify

I want to simplify this code, can someone help me please

This my code right now

$path_booth = $req->file('image_booth')->store('images', 's3');
$path_masak   = $req->file('image_masak')->store('images', 's3');
$path_icip = $req->file('image_icip')->store('images', 's3');
$path_selling   = $req->file('image_selling')->store('images', 's3');

$url_booth = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path_booth);
$url_masak   = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path_masak);
$url_icip = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path_icip);
$url_selling   = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path_selling);
$url_arr         = array();

array_push($url_arr, $url_booth);
array_push($url_arr, $url_masak);
array_push($url_arr, $url_icip);
array_push($url_arr, $url_selling);
$url = implode(";", $url_arr);

I want to create function that can insert to url, can it?

Comment: what programming language is this? Also, please format your code so it can be differentiated from text

Comment: After the end of this code (`$url = implode...`), do you ever use the intermediate variables (e.g. `path_booth`, `url_booth`) again? If not, then I suggest you dispense with them and use a loop; that will remove redundancy, and make the code shorter and simpler..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.